# Python CCXT How to make USDT available for trading from the deposit

Tags: python-3.x, ccxt

OS: MacOS
Language: Python3
Framework: CCXT

Hi there,
I'm using the following method to transfer USDT from my Binance account to Bigone:

```
deposit_address = await bigoneEx.fetch_deposit_address('USDT')
big_one_bsc_address = getBbsAddress(deposit_address) # Here I loop through the Array and return the address of the BSC network
try:
   withdraw_info = await binanceEx.withdraw('USDT', 10, big_one_bsc_address, params = {'network': 'BSC'})
except (NetworkError, RequestTimeout) as e:
   print(type(e).__name__, str(e))
   break
```

And this is all, I have a little bit more code, which check if the transfer was successful.
The first question I have, is there a another way to transfer the USDT via the BSC network? Because the variable withdraw_info, has only the id set, and the rest of the parameters inside this response json are set to "None".

When transferring is done, I get a message from the Bigone app that the coins are arrived in my Bigone acount, but calling the method:

```
balance = await bigoneEx.fetch_balance()
total_usdt_amount = balance['USDT']['total']
free_usdt_amount = balance['USDT']['free']
used_usdt_amount = balance['USDT']['used']
```

and all of the shows: 0.0

What I would like to do is, to buy another coins for USDT, how can I get the entire USDT amount, I found a solution to make an market order directly from my fundings acount:

```
bigone_order = bigoneEx.create_order('BTC', 'market', 'buy', 'amount_of_btc', None, params={'method': 'funding'})
```

To determine the amount_of_btc first I need to now how much USDT I have, and here is what I'm looking for:

1. How do I get the entire USDT amount from my funding account
2. Do one know if the method is correct (the params especially)
3. Is there a way to transfer the USDT from my funding account to the main account, so that calling the method .fetch_balance I can see my USDT in 'free'

Thank you